# Odoo website sections with different top menu

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I try to implement separate top menu's in multiple sections of pages in a single Odoo 12 website. Each section have own top menu (=menu on the top of the webpage). The pages are all in one Odoo website. Based on what section the current page is on, the top menu should contain section specific menu.

In my case the sections are two "language" versions of almost the same pages. The page contents will differ so the standard multi-lingual Odoo website is not suitable for this case. Also the dns-name for both sections should be the same, so I don't want to use multi website.

Currently I have implemented this with if-logic in qweb templates with fixed html for another menu. This is not a good solution because it is hard for normal Odoo user to update the html template. It would be better to utilize build in Odoo menu model.

Odoo 12 website menu structure without modifications can have multiple root levels (=no parent id set). I could not figure out in standard Odoo how to set which of these each page would use. The source code seems to select always first menu by id in addons/website/models/website.py line 123.

```
website.menu_id = Menu.search([('parent_id', '=', False), ('website_id', '=', website.id)], order='id', limit=1).id
```

Is there possibility to specify different sections with unique top menu for one website, or specify top menu on page level so that pages on each "section" would be linked to certain menu? If not possible in standard Odoo, is there already a module for this? If not, where would it make sense to start coding and extend this capability as a new module?